# Set fan speed temporarily to 100%

Tags: nvidia, overheating, fan, temperature

**Question:** Is there a program or an easy way (bash script) to set the fan speed to 100% for some time, for example a console program like `setfanspeedtomax`, such that when I press `^C`, the fan is controlled automatically again? (I don't want to change the automatic fan control profile.)

**Background:** I have an ASUS UX501JW-CN245T laptop, Debian 8. The standard fan profile works fine but whenever I use oclHashcat with CUDA, the GPU temperature exceeds 90°C which can be avoided by setting the fan speed to maximum: When I tried to use pwmconfig, I got some error

```
root@UX501JW:/# pwmconfig
# pwmconfig revision 6166 (2013-05-01)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

Found the following devices:
   hwmon0 is acpitz
   hwmon1 is coretemp
   hwmon2 is asus

Found the following PWM controls:
   hwmon2/pwm1           current value: 85
hwmon2/pwm1 is currently setup for automatic speed control.
In general, automatic mode is preferred over manual mode, as
it is more efficient and it reacts faster. Are you sure that
you want to setup this output for manual control? (n) y

Giving the fans some time to reach full speed...
Found the following fan sensors:
   hwmon2/fan1_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!

There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0.
Make sure you have a 3-wire fan connected.
You may also need to increase the fan divisors.
See doc/fan-divisors for more information.
```

and the fan went on full speed and stayed like that for some reason. I tested oclHashcat again and with the fans running at full speed, the GPU temperature did not exceed 84°C. I then had to shut down to get the automatic fan control back.

Answer (score 0):

This command sets the fans to 100%:
nvidia-settings -a GPUTargetFanSpeed=100

Source:
https://pingtrip.com/posts/headless-hashcat-server

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.